# Condensing a sparse array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sparse-array

I have an array of elements where the entries are sparse.  How can I easily condense the sparse array into a dense array so that I don't have to keep checking for null and undefined values every time I loop through the data?

Here is some example data:

```
var sparse = [];
sparse[1] = undefined;
sparse[5] = 3;
sparse[10] = null;

var dense = sparseToDenseArray(sparse);
// dense should be [3]
```

Comment: why would dense be `[3]` instead of `[undefined, 3, null]`? `1 in sparse === true` but `0 in sparse === false`, so only the ones where you didn’t set values are really missing. if you want to do that, the answer is `var dense = []; sparse.forEach(function(e) { dense.push(e) })`, as this only loops over the existing items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In vanilla JS, works on all browsers:

```
function filt(a) { 
 var b = []; 
 for(var i = 0;i < a.length;i++) { 
  if (a[i] !== undefined && a[i] !== null) { 
   b.push(a[i]); 
  }
 } 
 return b; 
}

> filt([1,undefined,3])
[1, 3]
```

Comment: (a[i] !== undefined) is redundant as (a[i] != null) comprises both cases (null and undefined)

Comment: a[i] != null also matches all the other falsy stuff and I think needs to be corrected to !== , not removed.

Comment: `a[i] != null` does *not* “matches all the other falsy stuff”. It is try IFF `a[i]` is `undefined` or `null`.
In this case `if (a[i] !== undefined && a[i] !== null)` is strictly equivalent to `if (a[i] != null)`, and could be simplified.

Answer (score 21):

In ES2017 (ES8) this is as easy as `Object.values(sparseArray)`

For example:

```js
const sparseArray = [, , 'foo', 'bar', , 'baz', ,];
const compactArray = Object.values(sparseArray);
console.log(compactArray);
```

Note though that this method only removes *gaps*, shifting down the indexes of existing array elements as required. It does not remove elements explicitly set to `undefined` or `null`.

Answer (score 14):

You can use `filter()` which is compatible with Firefox, Chrome, IE 9, Opera, and Safari web browsers.

According to David Flanagan, in *Javascript: The Definitive Guide*, an easy way of transforming a sparse array to a dense array is to use a filter on it like so:

```
var dense = sparse.filter(function (x) { return x !== undefined && x != null; });
```

This works since `filter()` skips missing elements and only returns `true` if x is not `undefined` or `null`.

If `filter()` is not supported, this will compact a sparse array:

```
var compacted = [];

for(var i = 0; i < sparse.length; i++)
    if(i in sparse)
        compacted.push(sparse[i]);
```

An exact equivalent of the `filter()` example is:

```
var compacted = [];

for(var i = 0; i < sparse.length; i++)
    if(sparse[i] != null)
        compacted.push(sparse[i]);
```

Comment: No, those last two code snippets are not equivalent. The `in` operator checks whether a property exists whereas equality operators (`==`, `!=`, `===`, `!==`) can tell you nothing about that.

Comment: Your second code snippet will not do what the OP is after, in fact: it will give you `[undefined, 3, null]` for the array in the question.

Comment: @TimDown I think you are refering to Charmander's first code snippet.

Comment: @TimDown: I appear to have worded that ambiguously and I apologize. By "the above" I meant the original `filter()` example. I will correct it immediately.

Comment: @Ivan: The second last one then. Depends whether you count the one-liner using `filter`.

Comment: @TimDown: In regards the second code snippet returning an incorrect value - it does not. The use of `!=` as opposed to `!==` ensures that `undefined` is not included.

Comment: @Charmander the code snippet with `if(i in sparse)` returns  `[undefined, 3, null]`.

Comment: @Charmander: Yes, I specifically meant the one using the `in` operator.

Comment: @TimDown: Yes, that's why I provided the alternative - I don't entirely agree that compacting a sparse array also means removing all `undefined` and `null` values within.

Comment: ... but @Ivan, you are free to take that example out if you do not agree with that disagreement.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include underscore.js in your code, you can use the [compact](http://underscorejs.org/#compact) function on your array.

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe there is so limited answers in here. First of all i think there are better, faster solutions to condensing a sparse array. I guess a sparse array doesn't mean an array with holes of undefined items ([What exactly is a dense array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39030196/4543207)). A sparse array should be  an array where actually there are no keys exists other than the keys which belong to the existing but sparse values. So if we iterate over the keys we should be doing our job more efficiently and faster.

Ok i compiled a test below to show you the performance of several methods to condense a sparse array.

```js
var ts = 0,
    te = 0,
sparse = new Array(10000000),
 dense = [];
[sparse[2499999], sparse[4999999], sparse[9999999]] = ["first one", "middle one", "last one"];

ts = performance.now();
dense = Object.keys(sparse).map(k => sparse[k]);
te = performance.now();
console.log(dense, "Okeys and map resulted in :" +(te-ts)+ "msecs");

dense = [];

ts = performance.now();
for (var key in sparse) dense.push(sparse[key]);
te = performance.now();
console.log(dense, "for in loop resulted in :" +(te-ts)+ "msecs");

dense = [];

ts = performance.now();
dense = sparse.filter(function (x) { return x !== undefined && x !== null; });
te = performance.now();
console.log(dense, "Array filter resulted in :" +(te-ts)+ "msecs");

dense = [];

ts = performance.now();
for (var i = 0, len = sparse.length; i < len; i++) sparse[i] !== undefined &&
                                                   sparse[i] !== null      &&
                                                   dense.push(sparse[i]);
te = performance.now();
console.log(dense, "For loop resulted in :" +(te-ts)+ "msecs");
```

Answer (score 0):

> filter is a JavaScript extension to the ECMA-262 standard; as such it
>   may not be present in other implementations of the standard. You can
>   work around this by inserting the following code at the beginning of
>   your scripts, allowing use of filter in ECMA-262 implementations which
>   do not natively support it. Reference : [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

A cross browser solution using `filter`

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {  // Add the filter method to the 'Array prototype' if it's not available
    Array.prototype.filter = function(fun /*, thisp*/) {
        var len = this.length >>> 0;
        if (typeof fun != "function") {
            throw new TypeError();
        }

        var res = [];
        var thisp = arguments[1]; 
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (i in this) {
                var val = this[i];
                if (fun.call(thisp, val, i, this)) {
                    res.push(val);
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    };
}

var sparse = [];
sparse[1] = undefined;
sparse[5] = 3;
sparse[10] = null;

dense=sparse.filter(function(a){ //Call the `filter` method
    return a!== undefined && a != null;
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/t73Gt/1/)