# Search and match

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sheet Import

```
 id  | Price | c,e
s123 |  99   |  A@
s124 |  98   |  B@
s125 |  97   |  C@
r78  |  35   |  D@
```

This is the code:

```
function buscarCe2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Import")
  var lr = s.getLastRow()
  var lookup = s.getRange(2, 1, lr - 1, 3).getValues();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Pricelist") 
  var lr1 = s1.getLastRow()
  var range = s1.getRange(2, 1, lr1 - 1, 3).getValues();
  var lookupRange = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lookup.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < range.length; j++) {
      if (lookup[i][0] == range[j][0]) {
      }
    }  
  }
  s1.getRange(2, 3, lookupRange.length).setValues(lookupRange);
}
```

**ACTUAL RESULT:**
I tried  `lookupRange.push()` inside the `if` block:
Sheet Pricelist

```
id   |  Price |  c,e
a453 |  99    |   A@
a111 |  98    |   D@
s123 |  97    |
r78  |  35    |
```

With the script I do not achieve the match between `s123 A @` and `r78 D @`. I'm not sure what to do next.

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

Sheet Pricelist

```
id   |  Price |  c,e
a453 |   99   |
a111 |   98   |
s123 |   97   |  A@
r78  |   35   |  D@
```

Comment: I'm surprised this gives any output.  You have nothing in your `if` statement.  So the code is going to run through all of the combinations in the nested `for` statements, and then move on to `s1.getRange`, and most likely spit out whatever happened to be in the array.  That line specifically tells it to output to Row 2 Column 3, so that part makes sense.  It won't line up with your desired row because you aren't asking it to.  I think you need to move the `s1.getRange` line inside the `if` statement, and then change the address:  `s1.getRange(2, j+1).setValues(lookupRange);`.

Comment: What's the desired output? What's wrong with the code so far?

Comment: Excuse the English
for (var i = 0; i <lookup.length; i ++) {
      for (var j = 0; j <range.length; j ++) {
        if (lookup [i] [0] == range [j] [0]) {
           lookupRange.push ([lookup [i] [2]]);
}}}
   s1.getRange (2, j + 1) .setValues (lookupRange);

Incorrect interval height; it was 2 but it should be 1. (line 74, file "Code") Ignore

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: lookupRange is an empty single dimension array which is not appropriate for use in setValues(). Check the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the empty 2D array `lookupRange`, You can try:

#### From:

```
var lookupRange = [];
```

#### To:

```
var lookupRange = Array.apply(null,Array(range.length)).map(function(e){ return [""];});
```

or

```
var lookupRange = s1.getRange(2, 3, range.length).getValues(); //Assuming they're empty.
```

- `Array(range.length)` creates a sparse array of length equal to length of `range`
- `Array.apply()` spreads the sparse array and converts it to dense array, which can then be mapped to arrays with empty strings `[""]`
- Alternatively, Easy way is just to getValues() from sheet with empty values

#### Modified Script:

```
function buscarCe2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Import")
  var lr = s.getLastRow()
  var lookup = s.getRange(2, 1, lr - 1, 3).getValues();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName("Pricelist") 
  var lr1 = s1.getLastRow()
  var range = s1.getRange(2, 1, lr1 - 1, 3).getValues();
  var lookupRange = Array.apply(null,Array(range.length)).map(function(e){ return [""];});
  for (var i = 0; i < lookup.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < range.length; j++) {
        if (lookup[i][0] == range[j][0]) {
          lookupRange[j][0]=lookup[i][2];
        }    
      }  
    }
  s1.getRange(2, 3, lookupRange.length).setValues(lookupRange);
}
```

#### Further Reading:

- [Dense Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030196/what-exactly-is-a-dense-array)
- [Array#flat(Alternatives)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [Array#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: I'm a novice in script, I still can not locate the range (r2, fc) and place the values obtained A@ D@.
s1.getRange (?) .setValues (lookupRange);
Thank you,

Comment: @Luis I have edited my answer to include the full script.

Comment: @Luis  Check now. It should've been `[""]` instead of `[]`. Edited my answer above.

Comment: Estimate I congratulate you.
Much health for you and yours-
Thank you.