# Array.prototype.map() returns empty item but Array.prototype.forEach() doesn't

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach, array.prototype.map

I experience a weird behaviour from `.map()`. It returns an empty item whilst `.forEach()` doesn't.

Here's the code:

```
class Entry {
    constructor(data) {
        this.name = data[0],
        this.age = data[1],
        this.school = data[2]
    };

    get organised() {
        return this.organise();
    };

    organise() {
        const data = {
            name: this.name,
            school: this.school
        };
        return data;
    }
}

const getDataForEach = (obj) => {
    let r = [];
    obj.forEach((i) => {
        const e = new Entry(i);
        r.push(e.organised);
    });
    return r;
};
getDataForEach(input); // return normal object array [{...}, {...}, ...]
```

But if I use `.map()`, it returns an object array with the first item is empty. The other items are the same as result from `.forEach()`.

```
const getDataMap = (obj) => {
    return obj.map((i) => {
        const e = new Entry(i);
        console.log(e) // return normal [{...}]
        console.log(e.organised) // return normal {...}
        return e.organised;
    });
};
getDataMap(input); // return an object array with the first item empty [<1 empty item>, {...}, {...}, ...]
```

Have you experienced anything similar to this?

Comment: Are you sure that `e.organized` isn't returning nothing?

Comment: JavaScript has no "empty" value. Do you mean the first element is `undefined`?

Comment: @Explosion Pills I'm sure. If it does, then there won't be other entries.

Comment: @undefined: that's the result from console.log(), if I print it out in a .txt file, I get this: 0,,1,[Object], 2,[Object]...

Comment: that seems like expected behavior for [sparse arrays](http://2ality.com/2012/06/dense-arrays.html)

Comment: @Slai: Thank you for the link. So that's a normal behaviour for arrays in Javascript? Sometimes they have "holes"?

Comment: yes, they are objects where the positive integer keys are used. For example `[, 2]` is similar to `{ "1": 2, "length": 2 }`

Comment: see second example here for a bit more detail https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180204/finding-all-pairs-of-elements-in-an-array-that-sum-to-a-target-value/180264#180264

Comment: one alternative is `Object.values(obj).map` (but not available in IE) https://stackoverflow.com/a/41802221/1383168

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When processing a sparse array, both `map` and `forEach()` skip elements that have never been assigned or have been deleted.

The difference, though, is that `map` constructs the resulting array itself, while your `forEach()` code is pushing onto the result array. `push()` will never create holes in the array, since it always appends a new element at the current length, but `map()` can. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Description) points out:

> Due to the algorithm defined in the specification if the array which map was called upon is sparse, resulting array will also be sparse keeping same indices blank.

You would get a result similar to `map` if you changed the `forEach` code to use the input array indices rather than using `push`, e.g.

```
const getDataForEach = (obj) => {
    let r = [];
    obj.forEach((i, index) => {
        const e = new Entry(i);
        r[index] = e.organised;
    });
    return r;
};
```